# C# sort listviewitems by color

Tags: c#, listview

How would I sort my list view items by color? I have 4  colors: red, yellow, blue, and black. Right now it's a mix of color, how would I organized them all in red, yellow, blue, and black in order?

Should be able to sort by itself without clicking any column headers...

I tried to google, cannot find what I was looking for.

Comment: show your code to enable us to help you

Comment: http://www.wpftutorial.net/dataviews.html

Comment: There are various solutions like a enum or by color number ( all colors have a number. For example red = ff0000 or black = 000000).